# Text selection position in pdf.js

Tags: pdf.js

I have the text selection enabled in my PDF.js. When a user selects some text I would like to know what is the starting position of that selection in reference to the underlying file stream. The idea is to return the absolute position of the selection within the file.

Example:
E.g. the selected text might be returned with the absolute position char=300,312

> Lore ipsum **My Selection** Lore ipsum Lore ipsum Lore ipsum Lore

Is this kind of reverse engineering even possible with PDF.js?